# How to return two substrings separated by whitespace from NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, algorithm, nsstring

Given a string "a b c d", I'd like to return substrings in the following format:

"a b", 
"b c", 
"c d"

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my mind around this concept in the most efficient way possible in time it takes to complete.

Code format:

```
NSString *sentence = @"Hello I am a string";
```

I want this to return the following:

"Hello I",
"I am",
"am a",
"a string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString * sentence = @"Hello I am a string";
NSArray * components = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray * substrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < components.count - 1; i++) {
    NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", components[i], components[i+1]];
    [substrings addObject:str];
}

for (NSString * str in substrings) {
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Comment: This is great! I wonder if there is possible a faster way though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
           test=@"abcd";
 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@", [test substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)],[test substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,2)],
                       [test substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)]];
```

Comment: Ah nice. I'm also hoping that it is assuming that I don't really know where all the white spaces are located so that if it's an epically long string I can just find where all the whitespaces are and just find the two substrings that are separated by the whitespace.